# Q: Azeroth Core Chat Log System

Tags: logging, chat, azerothcore

Hi I am trying to find a way to store / download the chat logs and loot logs from Azeroth Core.
The 3 other posts here no longer seem to function with any of the recent changes to AC.

Can someone run me through the process to get them on the new set up.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can find everything about logging the specific points that you can log in the worldserver.conf under the header "LOGGING SYSTEM SETTINGS"

If you want to learn how to specifically set up different loggings and in your case to store/write to a file you can read up on it on the wiki https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/logging-configuration